# Rust - clousures and generic types

Tags: generics, rust, traits

To be honest, it's hard for me to describe the problem in words, so i'll show the code right away:

```
// SomeType / SomeTrait

struct SomeType;

trait SomeTrait {
    fn do_sth() -> &'static str;
}

impl SomeTrait for SomeType {
    fn do_sth() -> &'static str {
        "do_sth()"
    }
}

// SomeOtherType / SomeOtherTrait

struct SomeOtherType;

impl SomeOtherType {
    fn get_some_trait<C>(&self, c: C)
    where
        C: Fn(SomeType), // Takes clousure, clousure have to get `SomeType`-type paramm 
    {
        c(SomeType);
    }
}

trait SomeOtherTrait {
    fn perform_sth<C, D>(&self, c: C)
    where
        D: SomeTrait,
        C: Fn(&D) -> &'static str; // Takes clousure, clousure have to get type that implements SomeTrait
}

impl SomeOtherTrait for SomeOtherType {
    fn perform_sth<C, D>(&self, c: C)
    where
        D: SomeTrait,
        C: Fn(&D) -> &'static str,
    {
        self.get_some_trait(|arg: SomeType| {
            c(&arg); // <- Problem
            // Error: expected type parameter `D`, found struct `SomeType`
            // But `D: SomeTrait` and SomeType implements `SomeTrait`
        });
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The code above is a simplified model of the situation I find myself in.

If i have `|arg: SomeType|`, the `c` clousure takes reference to generic type `T`, that implements `SomeType` - why can't i pass `arg` as argument for `c`?

Thank you in advance for your help in solving the problem. I apologise for any mistakes in my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your current definition of `SomeOtherTrait` allows this since it leaves filling in the `D` parameter to the caller by defining it on `perform_sth` but you internally already bind it to be `SomeType` by virtue of `SomeOtherType::get_some_trait`.

If you introduce a generic parameter `D` on `SomeOtherTrait`, you can bind `D` in a given type's implementation of `SomeOtherTrait` to whatever it requires:

```
trait SomeOtherTrait<D> {
    fn perform_sth<C>(&self, c: C)
    where
        D: SomeTrait,
        C: Fn(&D) -> &'static str; // Takes clousure, clousure have to get type that implements SomeTrait
}

impl SomeOtherTrait<SomeType> for SomeOtherType {
    fn perform_sth<C>(&self, c: C)
    where
        C: Fn(&SomeType) -> &'static str,
    {
        self.get_some_trait(|arg| {
            c(&arg);
        });
    }
}
```

The other option is adjusting `get_some_trait` to be generic over the argument to `c`, although you'll then need to be able to construct it, e.g. through `D::Default()`:

```
// ...
struct SomeOtherType;

impl SomeOtherType {
    fn get_some_trait<C, D>(&self, c: C)
    where
        D: Default,
        C: Fn(D), // Takes clousure, clousure have to get `SomeType`-type paramm
    {
        c(D::default());
    }
}
// ...
```

which in turn entails adding the `D: Default` bound to `SomeOtherTrait::perform_sth`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that this will only work if `D` is `SomeType`. Say for example I have the code bellow:

```rust
struct Foo;

impl SomeTrait for Foo {
    fn do_sth() -> &'static str {
        "Foo"
    }
}

SomeOtherType.perform_sth::<_, Foo>(|_: &Foo| "Bla" );
```

This code is completely valid, but the current implementation of `perform_sth` attempts to use `SomeType` despite my closure expecting `Foo` should be used instead.